# Patricia Merkle tree

Tags: go-ethereum

In the patricia merkle tree, each `shortnode` represent a key-value mapping which saved in DB.

`Key = Hash(Value)`

`Value = rlp.encode(node)`

There is question that if a node been updated and the node's value changed. When the node saved to DB, the key of the node change! But i didn't find any reorgnization tree code.

How does patricia merkle tree work during the node updating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super high-level answer: all nodes, on the road from the changed node to the root, change.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the merkle tree in ethereum `reorg` the tree while `update` method called. And the subcall of `update` method is `insert` function.

That's to say, when we want to update a tree node's value, a new node will be created and insert to the `appropriate` position with specific key and the old node will be reserved to represent a historical state.

Here is a [Link](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/11/15/merkling-in-ethereum/), which described the detail.